# Split and delete a video clip, speeding up undeleted clip keeps deleted section

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

Let's say I added a video clip into the video editor, and I split it in half and deleted the half end of the video. Now, when I attempt to speed up the first portion of the video(undeleted) the deleted portion returns as part of the sped up version of the clip. How do I make sure the deleted clip is gone, and doesn't return when I try to speed up just the first portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press SHIFT-K (hold split) instead of K (just split). This does exactly what you want. It deletes everything after the cut.

Comment: What exactly does shift-K do compared to just k?

Comment: It really cuts the end off. So if you extend it, you will never see again the cut part